# Java final field compile-time constant expression

Tags: java, final, jls

The below text is from jls http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3

> Even then, there are a number of complications. If a final field is
> initialized to a compile-time constant expression (§15.28) in the
> field declaration, changes to the final field may not be observed,
> since uses of that final field are replaced at compile time with the
> value of the constant expression.

Can anyone please give me better explanation for the above. I couldn't understand the statement *"changes to the final field may not be observed"*. May with the help of example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I couldn't understand the statement changes to the final field may not be observed

It tells that , if a final variable is declared as compile time constant then any change made in the final variable using **reflection API** further in program will not be visible to the program during execution.
For example consider the code given below:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
class ChangeFinal 
{
    private final int x = 20;//compile time constant
    public static void change(ChangeFinal cf)
    {
        try
        {
            Class clazz = ChangeFinal.class;
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("x");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(cf , 190);//changed x to 190 for object cf
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ChangeFinal cf = new ChangeFinal();
        System.out.println(cf.x);//prints 20
        change(cf);
        System.out.println(cf.x);//prints 20
    }
}
```

The Output of the above code is:

```
20
20
```

**WHY?**
The answer lies in the output provided by `javap -c` command for public static void main:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new     #3; //class ChangeFinal
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #11; //Method "<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1
   8:   getstatic       #12; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   11:  aload_1
   12:  invokevirtual   #13; //Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Cla
ss;
   15:  pop
   16:  bipush  20
   18:  invokevirtual   #14; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
   21:  aload_1
   22:  invokestatic    #15; //Method change:(LChangeFinal;)V
   25:  getstatic       #12; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   28:  aload_1
   29:  invokevirtual   #13; //Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Cla
ss;
   32:  pop
   33:  bipush  20
   35:  invokevirtual   #14; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
   38:  return

}
```

At line 16 (before `changeFinal` method is called)the value of `cf.x` is hardcoded to `20` . And at line 33 (after `changeFinal` method is called) the value of `cf.x` is again hardcoded to `20`. Therefore , Although the change in the value of final variable `x` is done successfully by  `reflection API` during execution, but because of `x` being a compile time constant it is showing its constant value `20`.

Answer (score 4):

It means if in a class you have this:

```
public class Foo {
    public final boolean fooBoolean = true; // true is a constant expression
    public final int fooInt = 5; // 5 is a constant expression
}
```

At compile time any reference to `Foo.fooBoolean` may be replaced with `true`, and references to `Foo.fooInt` may be replaced by `5`. If at runtime you later change either of those final fields via reflection, the code referencing it (as it was written) may never see it.

Comment: An other example is if you change fooInt to 6 in the above class, and then recompile this Foo class, without recompiling classes which uses the foo class. Then these other classe might still read fooInt to be 5 instead of 6.

Comment: @MTilsted Good example. It's really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible for a Java program to observe a `final` field having two different values at different times, even without reflection, without recompiling multiple versions of the class, and without anything along those lines. Consider the class below:

```java
class X {
    static final int x = getX();
    
    static int getX() {
        System.out.println("X.x is now " + X.x);
        return 1;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("X.x is now " + X.x);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
X.x is now 0
X.x is now 1
```

This happens because some of the code (the first `println`) is executed before the field's value is assigned, so that code observes the field's default initial value of 0. The field has a default initial value before it is assigned, *even though it is final*, because it is not a *constant* field. The text you quoted from the JLS says this kind of thing cannot happen if the field is declared as a constant.